# How to go about designing a program that identifies corn fields on a map?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, image-processing, convolution

I am working on a project that identifies corn fields on a map (satellite imagery), given the latitude/longitude coordinates of known corn fields.

My plan is to use a deep learning convolutional neural network (CNN) to accomplish this task. I have previously built a program that can classify a digit from an image using a CNN trained with the MINST dataset. However, with that program, it was identifying whether the entire image was of a certain class (a certain digit). In this program, I am trying to identify where the corn fields are, so I need to identify several parts of the image as a corn field or not.

My current plan is this:
To train the CNN on the parts of the training images that are known to have corn fields (extracting the features of corn fields), and then on the actual satellite image, performing a process similar to convolution—analyzing each x by x block of the image and determining whether the x by x block has a high enough probability to contain a corn field.

Would this be a solid strategy for tackling this problem? And how would I determine what would be considered a "high-enough" probability?

Comment: The term of art you're looking for is "image segmentation"

Comment: Every image of your dataset has a corn field?